# Firefox unable to scroll through navigation keys in element with hidden scroll

Tags: html, css, firefox, scroll

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c11khcak/13/. What I intend to do is simple - just hide the scrollbar of the element. The element should be otherwise scrollable as usual, both through mouse wheel and up/down navigation keys. This I am accomplishing though some basic css:

```
.parent{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child{
   height: 150px;
   width: 318px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
    width: 318px; 
}
```

Problem is, it is working fine in Webkit browsers, in Firefox, while it is scrollable through mouse wheel, pressing up/down keys is not scrolling it. How do I make it work in Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the *focus flag* ([Ref Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex)) of the `div`.

In order to reliably get the `div` to get focus on click, is to provide it with a `tabindex`. It depends on your use-case, whether you want to use a *negative*, a *zero* or a *positive* `tabindex`.

> If the value is a negative integer The user agent must set the
>   element's tabindex focus flag, but should not allow the element to be
>   reached using sequential focus navigation
>
> If the value is a zero The user agent must set the element's tabindex
>   focus flag, should allow the element to be reached using sequential
>   focus navigation, and should follow platform conventions to determine
>   the element's relative order.
>
> If the value is greater than zero The user agent must set the
>   element's tabindex focus flag, should allow the element to be reached
>   using sequential focus navigation, and should place the element in the
>   sequential focus navigation order

For your example to work, all you need to do is:

```
<div class="child" tabindex="0">
   ...
</div>
```

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/y1boh9v7/3/***

This should work across all browsers. (Tested against IE-11, GC-39, and FF-34)

---

Here is a snippet of the same, with a technique to hide scrollbars. You can completely hide scrollbars by increasing the padding. However, it has been left narrower in this example for ease of use. Should you decide to hide the scrollbars, you should then provide alternate mechanism to scroll using mouse, like a drag-to-pan kind of thing using Javascript.

The image in this snippet will pan on clicking the scollbars, or by clicking the image and then using the keyboard up-down-left-right to pan, or by touch-sliding.

***Snippet***:

```css
div.scrollParent {
    height: 240px; width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.scrollChild {
    height: 240px; width: 240px;
    padding: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
    overflow: auto; 
}
img { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="scrollParent">
    <div class="scrollChild" tabindex="0">
        <img src='http://lorempixel.com/320/320' />
    </div>
</div>
```

.

Comment: Christ! Since when does Stackoverflow has become a mini JSFiddle!

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Yup. These are called StackSnippets! Hope this serves your purpose.

Comment: Totally. This is the best answers, does the trick with the least amount of work. Will award the bounty once it allows me to..

Answer (score 2):

This looks like to be the case because Firefox does not focus the `.child` on click. You can work around this by js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.child').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.child').focus();
    });
});
```

When you click inside the child it will get focus and you can scroll up/down with the arrows.

See http://jsfiddle.net/c11khcak/14/ (tested in Firefox 36.0a2)

Comment: you don't need javascript at all. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

### HTML (for keys to work when div is clicked/focused)

```
<div class="child" tabindex='1'>
```

### CSS

```
.parent{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; right:-18px; left:0; bottom:-18px;
}

img {
  width: 318px; 
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

## [Demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/c11khcak/17/)